# How can image be inserted in each sections using jquery mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Here is my work http://jsfiddle.net/sanand29/hhcgsgo4/2/. The code is here    `<div id="line></div>
<ul>
   <li></li>
</ul>`

I am not able to get the image in center of each section. Even if the image is coming it is not responsive. Any help..

Comment: which image ? I only see lines.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique in JavaScript. If you want to identify groups of elements you it is better to use a class name, not an ID.

Comment: see the updated fiddle i have kept it for 2 sections for keeping it simple.. can u help

Comment: All i see is a line in the middle, no image. Where you have (../path/name.png) you can use (http://postimage.org/) to upload it and get the url so you can display it. Its free and i use it for demos such as the one you are doing

Comment: actually the horizontal line is just below the vertical one.. see this http://jsfiddle.net/sanand29/hhcgsgo4/ I am not getting the image in the center of each sections thats the problem